# How do I cleanly remove old Juniper Pulse installation from Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, launchd

The Console application on the Mac is continuously throwing log messages presumably because fragments of a previous install are still in place. I have tried Googling around for a solution and using grep to search through plist files for obvious strings. No luck so far.

Getting recurring error messages per the below:

```
May 26 19:12:53 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (net.juniper.AccessService[73727]): Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error = 2: No such file or directory, path = /Applications/Junos Pulse.app/Contents/Plugins/JUNS: 16G2136: xpcproxy + 11215 [1386][C3C8A771-3847-30E4-BE12-7941C4A2924D]: 0x2
May 26 19:12:53 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (net.juniper.AccessService): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Comment: You are right: the uninstall wasn't done correctly.[return]
Do you have an uninstaller coming with the `Junos Pulse` installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will have to locate where `Juniper` installed the `net.juniper.AccessService` daemon.

Here is a shell script made without a real case to test it (in blind mode), then beware of any errors and report them in comments so I will be able to fix it.

```
_plist1="net.juniper.AccessService.plist"
_plist2="net.juniper.UninstallPulse.plist"

export _plist1 _plist2

for _dir in /Library/LaunchDaemons /System/Library/LaunchDaemons ; do
    cd ${_dir}

    # check if the .plist is in this directory

    if [ -f ${_plist1} -o -f ${_plist2} ] ; then
        echo "found in ${_dir}"
        launchctl unload -w ${_plist1}
        launchctl unload -w ${_plist2}
        rm -i ${_plist1} ${_plist2}
    fi
done
```

1. Run this script without `root` priviledges.
   Check that the `echo` display the `plist` file is found in one of the 2 directories and the `launchctl` command issue an error because you don't
   have priviledge to stop this daemon.
2. If you didn't get any unexpected error message, then

   switch to `root` user:

   ```
   /usr/bin/sudo -s
   ```

   run this small script once more
   and answer `y` to the `rm` command to definetely remove the `Juiper` daemon.

   Then exit `root` user:

   ```
   exit
   ```

Comment: Changed /library/LaunchDaemons to /Library/LaunchDaemons (lower to upper case)

Comment: Output (not sudo): found in /Library/LaunchDaemons
/Library/LaunchDaemons/net.juniper.AccessService.plist: Could not find specified service
remove net.juniper.AccessService.plist?

Comment: Found a couple of files in /Library/LaunchDaemons:

Comment: MacBook-Pro:LaunchDaemons user$ ls *juniper*
net.juniper.AccessService.plist  net.juniper.UninstallPulse.plist
MacBook-Pro:LaunchDaemons user$

Comment: Removed manually with sudo rm \*juniper\*-Thanks for the help with this. BTW do you know how to put newlines in the comment section?

Comment: Beware, the remove of the plist files didn't stop the daemon. You should have used `launchctl unload -w` for both of them. Then and only then `rm` the `plist` files.

Comment: I improved my proposed shell script to take into account your return: there are 2 daemons.

Comment: A reboot should get you rid of the remaining useless daemons.[return]
Here is the way to check everything is clean:[return]
`/usr/bin/sudo launchctl list | grep -i juniper`